# Google Cloud Storage: upload parallel performance inside of Go routines is slow

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, concurrency, google-cloud-storage, goroutine

I have a Go web application which is uploading two files to two separate buckets using two separate clients in GCP using a method called `UploadFile()`.  When I call this function synchronously, each function call takes about 200ms (time N).

However, if I execute the exact same function inside of Go routine, each call *individually* takes 2N.  The entire resulting execution time also being doubled. Here's some example code:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(2)

// ASync upload 1
go func() {
    UploadObject(fileBytes, app.files.Bucket(app.config.storage.fileBucket), fileID)
    wg.Done()
}()

// ASync upload 2
go func() {
    UploadObject(fileBytes, app.files.Bucket(app.config.storage.regionalFileBucket, fileID) 
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()
```

Here is the implementation of UploadObject()

```
func UploadObject(uploadBytes []byte, bucket *storage.BucketHandle, objectName string) error {

    // Will cancel request after 30 seconds if upload is not complete.
    writeContext, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // Upload an object with storage.Writer.
    objectWriter := bucket.Object(objectName).NewWriter(writeContext)

    if _, err := io.Copy(objectWriter, bytes.NewBuffer(uploadBytes)); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("io.Copy: %v", err)
    }
    // Data can continue to be added to the file until the writer is closed.
    if err := objectWriter.Close(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Writer.Close: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

From inspecting the logs, and writing a bunch of timing around calls, I was able to note the correlation of objectWriter.Close() for both routines always being called one after another - as if to suggest they are locking/blocking each other, but I cant imagine how or why that would be the case.

I've also deployed this code to my GCP Cloud Run containers to try and isolate if it was just a localhost issue - again, no luck.

This also happens if only one of the two calls is in a Go routine. For example, if we do something like this, we still get the same 2N outcome for each functions runtime:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)

go func() {
    UploadObject(fileBytes, app.files.Bucket(app.config.storage.fileBucket), fileID)
    wg.Done()
}()

    UploadObject(fileBytes, app.files.Bucket(app.config.storage.regionalFileBucket, fileID) 
wg.Wait()
```

From my vantage point, I can't see any relationship between these cloud storage calls during execution, but perhaps maybe there is something about the Go GCP client and concurrency I don't yet understand.  Hoping someone can help shed some light.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `NewClient` for each concurrent request?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately using a new client didn't make any difference.  Google's official docs also state:

"Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. The methods of Client are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines."

Comment: The suggestion was to test your thesis that it's a concurrency issue in the client

Comment: Makes sense! Just wanted to clarify I had narrowed that down. I also just did a test where I instead opted to read from the bucket concurrently, swapping a read for a write in the above code.  It appears that the performance is not affected when reading (latency is identical for both parallel and sync).